# Erroneous behaviour of Java 8 Stream.sum()

Tags: java, algorithm, java-8

Today while solving [this](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/mandragora) question on HackerRank I used Array stream .sum() function to sum all the entries and proceeded with my algorithm. But for sum reason I found that my algorithm fails for some cases. I used diff to find out it passes 99% cases and for 1% the output is nearly equal but is less than the original answer. That's why I replaced the stream .sum() with a for loop and unexpectedly it passed all the test cases. I tried but couldn't ascertain this uncertain behaviour.

My implementation using stream.sum() :

```
public class MandragoraForest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        InputReader in = new InputReader(System.in);
        for (int i = in.nextInt(); i > 0; i--) {
            int number = in.nextInt();
            int[] h = new int[number];
            for (int j = 0; j < number; j++) h[j] = in.nextInt();
            System.out.println(new MandragoraForestSolver().solve(h));
        }
    }
}

class MandragoraForestSolver {

    public long solve(int[] h) {
        if (h.length==1) return h[0];
        Arrays.parallelSort(h);
        long sum = Arrays.stream(h)
                .sum();
        long ans = -1;

        for (long i=0, strength = 2; i<h.length; i++, strength++) {
            sum -= h[(int)i];
            ans = Math.max(ans, strength * sum);
        }
        return ans;
    }
}
```

Implementation without Java stream :

```
public class MandragoraForest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        InputReader in = new InputReader(System.in);
        for (int i = in.nextInt(); i > 0; i--) {
            int number = in.nextInt();
            int[] h = new int[number];
            long sum = 0;
            for (int j = 0; j < number; j++) {
                h[j] = in.nextInt();
                sum += h[j];
            }
            System.out.println(new MandragoraForestSolver().solve(h, sum));
        }
    }
}

class MandragoraForestSolver {

    public long solve(int[] h, long sum) {
        if (h.length==1) return h[0];
        Arrays.parallelSort(h);


        long ans = -1;

        for (long i=0, strength = 2; i<h.length; i++, strength++) {
            sum -= h[(int)i];
            ans = Math.max(ans, strength * sum);
        }
        return ans;
    }
}
```

Is there something that I'am missing out ? What could be the reason for this behaviour?

Comment: You're missing that `Arrays.stream(h).sum()` returns an `int`. Assigning it to a `long` does *not* make the summing happen in `long`, it's still being summed using `int`, and may cause numeric overflow.

Comment: Lol: "But for sum reason".

Comment: @principal-ideal-domain I had a laugh at that one too.

Comment: @principal-ideal-domain haha I didnt realise that :D

Comment: Because you thought all the time about sums ;)

Comment: @principal-ideal-domain I was in depression I couldn't solve this easy question on HackerRank and dreamed of winning ICPC haha

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is one significant difference between using a stream and a loop - the possibility of arithmetic overflow.

`Arrays.stream(int[])` returns an `IntStream`, whose `sum()` method returns an `int` result. If the sum exceeds `Integer.MAX_VALUE`, a silent integer overflow will occur.

However your loop sums by adding `int` values to a `long` total, which would not suffer from arithmetic overflow.

The sum of integers in one of the tests must exceed `Integer.MAX_VALUE`, testing that a `long` is used to (correctly) calculate the total.

---

If you want to use a stream to sum, you need to convert the `IntStream` to a `LongStream`, which you can do like this:

```
long sum = Arrays.stream(big).asLongStream().sum();
```

Comment: Is there a way I can use Java8 to get the correct answer ?

Comment: @MayurKulkarni see edited answer for java 8 stream solution that won't overflow

Comment: Thanks. Just a small doubt. Had the array been long, would the mapping be necessary then? would Arrays.stream(arr).sum() give the right answer?

Comment: @MayurKulkarni if the array had been `long[]`, but only stored `int` sized values, then your original code `Arrays.stream(arr).sum()` would work, because `Arrays.stream(long[])` returns a `LongStream`.

Comment: If the numbers were over Long.MAX_VALUE would you not run into the same issue? I know hackerrank is nice but interview questions are not. Also sorry for the 6 year bump!

Comment: @obesechicken13 but you'll find that the hackerrank question precludes long overflow, without which the problem would be meaningless. The usual way they do this is saying each value is `-1000000000 < i < 1000000000` and `n < 10000` or similar so the biggest sum would comfortably fit in a `long`.